# Insert reactive for fileInput (shapefile)

Tags: r, shiny

The code below is generating a scatterplot from a shapefile file. It is generating normally (see the attached image). However, instead of inserting the file directory directly into the code, I would like to insert the file through a fileInput. I inserted the fileInput below, but I would like help to adjust my server.
I believe it is necessary to adjust something related to the reactive.

Thank you so much!

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinythemes)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(rgdal)

function.cl<-function(df,k){
  
  shape<-readOGR(dsn="C:/Users/Jose Souza/Documents/Test",layer="Export_Output_3") 
  df<-shape@data
  
  #clusters
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 
  
  #all cluster data df1 and specific cluster df_spec_clust
  df1<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  df1$cluster<-as.factor(clusters)
    
  #Colors
  my_colors <- rainbow(length(df1$cluster))
  names(my_colors) <- df1$cluster
  
  #Scatter Plot for all clusters
  g <- ggplot(data = df1,  aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, color=cluster)) + 
    geom_point(aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), size = 4) +
    scale_color_manual("Legend", values = my_colors)
  plotGD <- g
  

  return(list(
    "Plot" = plotGD
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      fileInput("shp", h3("Shapefile Import"), multiple = TRUE, accept = c('.shp', '.dbf','.sbn', '.sbx', '.shx', '.prj')),
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                        
                          sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 2, max = 4, value = 3),
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Solution", plotOutput("ScatterPlot"))))
                        
                      ))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Modelcl<-reactive({
    function.cl(df,input$Slider)
  })
  
  output$ScatterPlot <- renderPlot({
    Modelcl()[[1]]
  })
     
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do in the server? Load selected files?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to do the clustering after uploading the files via fileInput. Wouldn't you have to make a reactive in server for this fileInput?

Comment: Why does function.cl have a df argument which you overwrite at the second line of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a new `path` argument to function.cl, remove `df` argument which is not used because assigned directly in the function
2. Use `eventReactive' in the server :

```
  Modelcl <- eventReactive(input$shp,{
    req(input$shp)
    mydir <- tempdir()
    on.exit(unlink(mydir))
    print(paste("names:",input$shp$name))
    file.copy(input$shp$datapath,file.path(mydir, input$shp$name) )
    function.cl(input$Slider,mydir)
    
  })
```

The difficulty was that readOGR expects a path but `fileInput` returns files.

The workaround was to create a temporary directory to get a path (**on the server**), to copy the `fileInput` files into it and to give the path of this temporary directory to `readOGR`for further processing.

This works with the example files you provided:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinythemes)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(rgdal)

function.cl<-function(k,path,filename){
  print(dir(path))
  shape<-readOGR(dsn=path,layer=filename) 
  df<-shape@data
  
  #clusters
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 
  
  #all cluster data df1 and specific cluster df_spec_clust
  df1<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  df1$cluster<-as.factor(clusters)
  
  #Colors
  my_colors <- rainbow(length(df1$cluster))
  names(my_colors) <- df1$cluster
  
  #Scatter Plot for all clusters
  g <- ggplot(data = df1,  aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, color=cluster)) + 
    geom_point(aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), size = 4) +
    scale_color_manual("Legend", values = my_colors)
  plotGD <- g
  
  
  return(list(
    "Plot" = plotGD
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      fileInput("shp", h3("Shapefile Import"), multiple = TRUE, accept = c('.shp', '.dbf','.sbn', '.sbx', '.shx', '.prj')),
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          
                          sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 2, max = 4, value = 3),
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Solution", plotOutput("ScatterPlot"))))
                        
                      ))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Modelcl<-reactive({
  #   function.cl(df,input$Slider,input$Filter1)
  # })
  Modelcl <- eventReactive(c(input$shp, input$Slider),{
    req(input$shp)
    tmpdir <- tempdir()
    on.exit(unlink(tmpdir))
    filename <- substr(input$shp$name[1],1,nchar(input$shp$name[1])-4)
    file.copy(input$shp$datapath,file.path(tmpdir,input$shp$name) )
    function.cl(input$Slider,tmpdir,filename)
    
  })
  
  output$ScatterPlot <- renderPlot({
    Modelcl()[[1]]
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Slider, {
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data)
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter1',
                      choices=sort(unique(abc$cluster)))
  }) 
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. I believe this is the way, but it still hasn't worked out. This code:```df <-shape @ data``` needs to be in the code, as it converts the shapefile into data.frame.  If you can insert all the code with the changes you would make, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks Waldi for updating the answer. I'm still doing tests, but I haven't been able to yet. My brother, who is helping me too, inserted the shapefile file of this issue in his github (https://github.com/JovaniSouza/JovaniSouza5/blob/master/shapefile.rar). So, I believe it’s easier for you to simulate too, if you can .Thanks again.

Comment: thanks for the files : which one(s) should readOGR open?

Comment: Hello friend, all the files in the zip are part of 1 shapefile. A shapefile consists of between 6 and 8 files on average. In the formula, the dsn is the path where the shapefile is saved, and Export_Output_3 is the name of the shapefile. Therefore, the readOGR is not choosing just one specific file, but all the files that make up the shapefile.

Comment: OK, got it, so you're not looking for a fileInput, but looking to find a path

Comment: readOGR seems to expect a path, this is the example you give. Not sure you can directly transmit the result of fileInput to a function expecting a path. See my edit : I propose to copy the uploaded files in a temp dir which is then given to readOGR. Another important argument is input$Filter1: where is it defined?

Comment: Thanks again for the answer Waldi. I am analyzing your code. Were you able to get it to work using the shapefile via fileInput? Regarding Filter 1, it was not important for what I wanted, I even apologize for having inserted it (I removed it in the code for this question).  I'm looking at this website (https://www.paulamoraga.com/book-geospatial/sec-shinyexample.html), which used shapefile data via fileInput. But I still haven't succeeded for my example. = /

Comment: Code wasn't yet working for me, but I didn't try to solve this yet because I didn't know what to do with filter1 : When you provide code examples in Stack Overflow, please try to reduce them to a Minimal Reproducible Example without unneeded parameters. I'm going to try to make this run with you new code.

Comment: Yes, my sincere apologies. I was focused on fileInput that I forgot those details. Thank you Waldi.

Comment: Code now running with explainations : give it a try!

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much, it appeared to me too. Just two things I would like to clarify: I found it strange that the Slider is no longer working after the scatterplot is generated in your code. The last question concerns the layer of this formula: ```shape <-readOGR (dsn = path, layer =" Export_Output_3 ")```. It is necessary to always be defined as the name of the shapefile, that is, whenever I insert another shapefile, will I need to update the code? Thanks again!

Comment: @Jose, slider works for me, added automatic filename modification

Comment: After you generate the scatterplot. I slide on the Slider, is the cluster automatically modified on the graph? In mine, it was static.

Comment: No the cluster is not automatically modified because eventReactive depends only on input$shp.  added c(input$shp, input$Slider) as trigger. Would be even better to separate this in 2 functions, one for file read, the other for slider management. But I'm going to quit here for now ;)

Comment: Now it's working perfectly, Waldi, I don't even know how to thank you, you helped me a lot. I hope to return this favor someday. Really, thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Waldi, do you have any suggestions for this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62567104/generate-scatterplot-both-by-shapefile-and-excel-in-shiny/62568117#62568117