# Generate scatterplot both by shapefile and excel in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

The codes below are working normally, the first code is generating a scatterplot by Shapefile and the second code is generating via Excel, both via fileInput. For simulation the data can be obtained through the following website:
https://github.com/JovaniSouza/JovaniSouza5/blob/master/shapefile.rar (shapefile)

https://github.com/JovaniSouza/JovaniSouza5/blob/master/Example.xlsx (excel)

The problem I am having is that I am not able to unify these codes, since I want to have only one code to generate the scatter plot and not two, could you help me solve this problem? In other words, I want to make it easier for the user to choose between using shapefile or excel data to generate the scatterplot in one code.

Thank you very much!

**SHAPEFILE**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinythemes)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(rgdal)

function.cl<-function(k,path,filename){
  print(dir(path))
  shape<-readOGR(dsn=path,layer=filename) 
  df<-shape@data
  
  #clusters
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 
  
  #all cluster data df1 and specific cluster df_spec_clust
  df1<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  df1$cluster<-as.factor(clusters)
  
  #Colors
  my_colors <- rainbow(length(df1$cluster))
  names(my_colors) <- df1$cluster
  
  #Scatter Plot for all clusters
  g <- ggplot(data = df1,  aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, color=cluster)) + 
    geom_point(aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), size = 4) +
    scale_color_manual("Legend", values = my_colors)
  plotGD <- g
  
  
  return(list(
    "Plot" = plotGD
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      fileInput("shp", h3("Shapefile Import"), multiple = TRUE, accept = c('.shp', '.dbf','.sbn', '.sbx', '.shx', '.prj')),
                        sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          
                          sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 2, max = 4, value = 3),
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Solution", plotOutput("ScatterPlot"))))
                        
                      ))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Modelcl <- eventReactive(c(input$shp, input$Slider),{
    req(input$shp)
    tmpdir <- tempdir()
    on.exit(unlink(tmpdir))
    filename <- substr(input$shp$name[1],1,nchar(input$shp$name[1])-4)
    file.copy(input$shp$datapath,file.path(tmpdir,input$shp$name) )
    function.cl(input$Slider,tmpdir,filename)
    
  })
  
  output$ScatterPlot <- renderPlot({
    Modelcl()[[1]]
  })
      
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**EXCEL**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinythemes)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(rgdal)

function.cl<-function(df,k){

  #clusters
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 
  
  #all cluster data df1 and specific cluster df_spec_clust
  df1<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  df1$cluster<-as.factor(clusters)
  
  #Colors
  my_colors <- rainbow(length(df1$cluster))
  names(my_colors) <- df1$cluster
  
  #Scatter Plot for all clusters
  g <- ggplot(data = df1,  aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, color=cluster)) + 
    geom_point(aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), size = 4) +
    scale_color_manual("Legend", values = my_colors)
  plotGD <- g
  
  
  return(list(
    "Plot" = plotGD
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      fileInput("data", h3("Excel import")), 
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          
                          sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 2, max = 4, value = 3),
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Solution", plotOutput("ScatterPlot"))))
                        
                      ))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  v <- reactiveValues(df = NULL)
  observeEvent(input$data, {
    v$df <- read_excel(input$data$datapath)
  })
  
  
  Modelcl<-reactive({if (!is.null(v$df)) {
    function.cl(v$df,input$Slider)
  }
  })
  
  
  output$ScatterPlot <- renderPlot({
    Modelcl()[[1]]
  })
   
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to check what type of file the user is loading and, depending on this, use the appropriate procedure. I did this in `observeEvent(input$data,`.

**SHAPEFILE AND EXCEL**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinythemes)
library(rdist)
library(openxlsx) #I use this library to read exel files.
library(geosphere)
library(rgdal)

function.cl<-function(df,k){
  
  #clusters
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 
  
  #all cluster data df1 and specific cluster df_spec_clust
  df1<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  df1$cluster<-as.factor(clusters)
  
  #Colors
  my_colors <- rainbow(length(df1$cluster))
  names(my_colors) <- df1$cluster
  
  #Scatter Plot for all clusters
  g <- ggplot(data = df1,  aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, color=cluster)) + 
    geom_point(aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), size = 4) +
    scale_color_manual("Legend", values = my_colors)
  plotGD <- g
  
  
  return(list(
    "Plot" = plotGD
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      fileInput("data", h3("Excel or Shapefile import"),
                                accept = c(".xlsx",".shp",".shx",".dbf"),
                                multiple= T),  
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          
                          sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 2, max = 4, value = 3)
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Solution", plotOutput("ScatterPlot"))))
                        
                      ))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  v <- reactiveValues(df = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$data, {
    if(any(grepl(".xlsx",input$data$name))){
      v$df <- read.xlsx(input$data$datapath) #Note that her I use read.xlsx form openxlsx.

    }else if(any(grepl(".shp",input$data$name))){
      
      shpDF <- input$data
      failed <- F
      
      if(!any(grepl(".shx",input$data$name))){
        failed<-T
      }

      if(!any(grepl(".dbf",input$data$name))){
        failed<-T
      }
      
      
      if(failed){
        print("You Need 3 files, '*.shp', '*shx' and '*.dbf'")
      }else{
        prevWD <- getwd()
        uploadDirectory <- dirname(shpDF$datapath[1])
        setwd(uploadDirectory)
        for (i in 1:nrow(shpDF)){
          file.rename(shpDF$datapath[i], shpDF$name[i])
        }
        shpName <- shpDF$name[grep(x=shpDF$name, pattern="*.shp")]
        shpName<-substr(shpName,1,nchar(shpName)-4)
        
        setwd(prevWD)
        shpFile<-readOGR(dsn=uploadDirectory,layer=shpName)
        
        v$df<-shpFile@data
      } 
    }else{
      print("Wrong File")
    }
  })
    
    
    Modelcl<-reactive({if (!is.null(v$df)) {
      function.cl(v$df,input$Slider)
    }
    })
    
    
    output$ScatterPlot <- renderPlot({
      Modelcl()[[1]]
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Of course there are many other solutions such as using radio Buttons to let the user specify the type of file they want to load before doing so.

A recommendation would be to use the parameter `acept` from `fileInput` function, to limit the types of files that the user can upload.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply Rolando. I generated the scatterplot by excel, however the shapefile (file .dbf) didn't work. Did it work for you?

Comment: Hi Jose, I provided it again and it did not work. I Change the answer so that instead of the ".dbf" file it reads the ".shp" file. But not the ".shp.xml" file but only ".shp" and now it works. I don't know why yesterday it worked with ".dbf"

Comment: Unfortunately I still haven't succeeded. I tested this new code of yours as you said, but the scatterplot is not being generated. Could test again, strange I was not getting. Only excel is working.

Comment: How strange for me it is working well, as in the image I added. Also I added the parameter I accepted the code but it really doesn't make any difference. Do you receive an error or does the graph just not appear?

Comment: Please try to take this code that you entered and play it on the console, it is giving an error. I want to see if solving this appears the scatter plot.

Comment: I saw that you edited the code. Executed, however when I insert the .shp file, it gives the following error: ```Warning: Error in ogrInfo: Cannot open layer [No stack trace available]```. It is interesting that yours works.

Comment: Read this [group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/FtI76rdvoHI), I note that we need you need to upload 3 necessary files (`shp` `shx`, `dbf`). I have re-edited the code again. Please try it.

Comment: Now it worked. So, I always need to insert these three files to work through the shapefile, right? Thank you so much friend for helping me.

Comment: That is good. At least, perhaps in other applications more files are needed than those that accompany the shp

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: Hi Rolando, any idea for the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62761896/questions-regarding-the-stplanr-package-in-r